# Polar pgfplots diagram adds additional whitespace with units library loaded

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polarplot

When doing polar plots in pgfplots (v1.10) I get additional whitespace when loading the units library. How can I get rid of that?

I did not observe this before since it is related to the direction of the y axis, as can be seen from the code below when comparing with a plot without the `xmin` and `xmax` setting. Removing the `units` library gives the correct spacing.

```
\documentclass[convert,TikZ]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{%
  units,
  polar,
}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
}


\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
    xmin=-180,xmax=180,
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (90,1) (180,1) (270,1) (360,1)};
  \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture showing the problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of it, even if you are loading units, by adding the option `use units=false`. This fixes it in your minimal example. Since it actually doesn't use units, it makes no harm there.

```
\documentclass[convert,TikZ]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{%
  units,
  polar,
}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
}


\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[use units=false,
    xmin=-180,xmax=180,
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (90,1) (180,1) (270,1) (360,1)};
  \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

If you let TikZ actually draw all nodes, you will see the node containing just whitespace, which causes that space:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
```

So, either

- check if siunitx produces whitespace even for an empty value and send a bug report
- send a bug report or feature request for pgfplots to actually switch off the labels instead of not printing them, which fails with units

or both.

[image: Nodes drawn]

Comment: Thanks, Stefan, that solves my problem. With your experience, can you tell me if this is a bug and worth a bug report? Or is there some concept I don't understand that causes this behaviour? (I tend to believe it's a bug but am not sure.)

Comment: @Chris I extended my answer a bit. Yes, it's worth a bug report.

Comment: Probably units library doesn't check if the labels are empty or not and appends itself next to the empty label.

Comment: Thanks for all your analysis. This is a bug in `pgfplots`. It will be fixed in version 1.11 (which comes in the next weeks).